# How to write multiple cells in different places in excel from Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I wanted to write multiple sheets in a certain font in Python like this:

```
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
from openpyxl import Workbook

import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font

def style_range_multiple_entries(file, cells_description, font): 

book = op.load_workbook(file) 

for k, description in enumerate(cells_description): 
 for t, list_item in enumerate(description[k]): 
 ws = book.worksheets[description[1]] 
 cell = ws.cell(description[2]) 
 cell.value = description[0] 
 cell.font = font 

book.save("styled.xlsx")

names = [[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], [0,0,0],['B2','B20',''B25]], (...) ]

font1 = Font(name='Calibri', size=16, bold=True)

style_range_multiple_entries('styled.xlsx',names, font1)
```

However there is something wrong with the loop..

I wanted to write in one sheet multiple cells in mulitple places, but the same font. Something like:

```
Sheet 1:
Cell'B2' = apple
Cell 'B20' = banana
Cell 'B25' = strawberry
```

Would you know what is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

P.S.:

I built a code which works for me like this:

```
def style_range(file, cells_description, font):

    book = op.load_workbook(file)

    for k, description in enumerate(cells_description):
        ws = book.worksheets[description[2]]
        cell = ws.cell(description[1])
        cell.value = description[0]
        cell.font = font
    book.save("styled.xlsx")
```

However I need to specified for the list something like this :

```
list = [['apple','B2',0], ['banana','B20',0], ['strawberry','B25',0], (...) ]
```

and I wanted to do it for a list like I defined above "names".

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Comment: thank you, I completed the code, hope it is better now ? I just started coding so I am not sure how much is good :)

Comment: The code doesn't look like it could work. Try something similar and build from that.

Comment: thanks, I built a code that works, but I need to add the items one by one...

Answer (score 1):

> *Question**: I wanted to do it for a list like I defined above "names"

You have to build a *Matrix* from your `names`.

> **Note**: Instead of building the `Matrix` afterwards, try to build it at once!

- Data == `list` of `list` of `list`

  ```
  names = [[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'raspberry'], 
            [0, 0, 0, 0], 
            ['B2', 'B20', 'B25', 'B30']
          ]]
  ```
- Get the dimension of the *Matrix*

  ```
  x_range = len(names[0])
  y_range = len(names[0][0])
  ```
- Build the *Matrix* from `names`

  ```
  names2 = []
  for y in range(y_range):
      names2.append([])
      for x in range(x_range):
          names2[y].append(names[0][x][y])
  ```

  > Alternative: **All in one line**
  >
  > ```
  > names2 = [[names[0][x][y] for x in range(x_range)] for y in range(y_range)]
  > ```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> print("names2:{}".format(names2))
> names2:[['apple', 0, 'B2'], ['banana', 0, 'B20'], ['strawberry', 0, 'B25'], ['raspberry', 0, 'B30']]
> ```

---

Reading your `list` of `list` of `list` and build one set of items:

> **Note**: There is no reason, to use `ws = book.worksheets[...` over and over again in a loop.
>   Get it **once** and pass it along your parameters, e.g. `style_one_cell(ws, names2, font)`

```
    for y in range(y_range):
        names2 = []
        for x in range(x_range):
            names2.append(names[0][x][y])

        print("style_one_cell({}, font)".format(names2))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> style_one_cell(['apple', 0, 'B2'], font)
> style_one_cell(['banana', 0, 'B20'], font)
> style_one_cell(['strawberry', 0, 'B25'], font)
> style_one_cell(['raspberry', 0, 'B30'], font)
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3***